# PHP stream_set_timeout and popen don't work together?

Tags: php, stream, popen

I use popen to open a stream to 2 other php-scripts:

```
$proc[0] = popen("/usr/srv/php /my/folder/myscript.php 0 &", "r"); 
$proc[1] = popen("/usr/srv/php /my/folder/myscript.php 1 &", "r");
if (!stream_set_timeout($proc[0], 1, 0)) print "stream_set_timeout failed on stream 1"; 
if (!stream_set_timeout($proc[1], 1, 0)) print "stream_set_timeout failed on stream 2";
```

What happens is that stream_set_timeout fails on both streams (returning false, tested on a linux- and a windows-machine with php 5.3.). Using fread on both stream works fine, but I want to read from both streams "simultaneously" and fread keeps blocking reading from the other stream (by the way, stream_set_blocking returns fails, too, returning false).

Any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: That it fails on Windows is expected because PHP doesn't use overlapping I/O in Windows, but it's strange it fails on Linux. I suggest you file a  bug report.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could someone please confirm that it doesn't work on linux before I file a bug report?

Comment: Have you tried removing the ampersand character from the end of the popen string?  `popen("/usr/srv/php /my/folder/myscript.php 0", "r")`

Comment: Yes, it's the same no matter with or without the ampersand.

Comment: `proc_open()` instead of `popen()` maybe?

Comment: I tried proc_open as well: Same effect.

Comment: Could someone please check if it works on your system? I wouldn't file a bug report if it's just a coincidence that it doesn't work on my machines.

Comment: Doesn't work for me also. I don't think that it **must** work though.